# Saltstack + New Relic: cmd.run returns "failed: mapping values are not allowed here;" error

Tags: newrelic, salt-stack

I am creating a recipe for SaltStack that installs New Relic Infrastructure monitoring on a minion. I'm trying to use the "cmd.run" option in conjunction with variables in my pillar file.

When I attempt to deploy, I get this error: failed: mapping values are not allowed here; line 3. The recipe I'm working with is here:

```
create-newrelic-config:
    cmd.run:
        - name: echo "license_key: {{pillar.newrelic.license_key}}" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
        - user: root
        - group: root
```

This returns:

```
out: project-django-support-01:
out:     Data failed to compile:
out: ----------
out:     Rendering SLS 'base:packages.newrelic' failed: mapping values are not allowed here; line 3
out: 
out: ---
out: create-newrelic-config:
out:     cmd.run:
out:         - name: echo "license_key: 000000000000000000000000000" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml    <======================
out:         - user: root
out:         - group: root
out: 
out: enable-newrelic-gpg:
out:     cmd.run:
out: [...]
out: ---
```

I'm wondering if I'm using the wrong syntax for the cmd.run function?

For reference -- though I don't think it's applicable here -- these are the install instructions I'm trying to replicate: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/new-relic-infrastructure/installation/install-infrastructure-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can achieve many tasks with cmd.run - but in fact salt often provides a [state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/index.html) that fits much better.

In this case you might want to use [`file.managed`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed):

### state.sls

```
/etc/newrelic.yml:
  file.managed:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644  # pick a mask that fits your setup.
    - contents_pillar: newrelic:license_key
```

### pillar.sls

```
newrelic:
  license_key: |
      license_key: 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234
```

This approach uses the `contents_pillar` to specify the file content. In your pillar file the `license_key` appears twice - first as the pillar key to refer to it from the state and second as the file contents for newrelic. This might be a little confusing.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense! Thanks!